# Merging depth maps for trinocular stereo

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-3d, perspectivecamera

I have a parallel trinocular setup where all 3 cameras are alligned in a collinear fashion as depicted below.

Left-Camera------------Centre-Camera---------------------------------Right-Camera

The baseline (distance between cameras) between left and centre camera is the shortest and the baseline between left and right camera is the longest.

In theory I can obtain 3 sets of disparity images using different camera combinations (L-R, L-C and C-R).I can generate depth maps (3D points) for each disparity map using Triangulation. I now have 3 depth maps.

The L-C combination has higher depth accuracy (measured distance is more accurate) for objects that are near (since the baseline is short) whereas
the L-R combination has higher depth accuracy for objects that are far(since the baseline is long). Similarly the C-R combination is accurate for objects at medium distance.

In stereo setups, normally we define the left (RGB) image as the reference image. In my project, by thresholding the depth values, I obtain an ROI on the reference image. For example I find all the pixels that have a depth value between 10-20m and find their respective pixel locations. In this case, I have a relationship between 3D points and their corresponding pixel location.

Since in normal stereo setups, we can have higher depth accuracy only for one of the two regions depending upon the baseline (near and far), I plan on using 3 cameras. This helps me to generate 3D points of higher accuracy for three regions (near, medium and far).

I now want to merge the 3 depth maps to obtain a global map. My problems are as follows -

1. How to merge the three depth maps ?
2. After merging, how do I know which depth value corresponds to which pixel location in the reference (Left RGB) image ?

Your help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I think that simple "merging" of depth maps (as matrices of values) is not possible, if you are thinking of a global 2D depth map as an image or a matrix of depth values. You can consider instead to merge the 3 set of 3D points with some similarity criteria like the distance (refining your point cloud). If they are too close, delete one of theme (pseudocode)

```
for i in range(points):
 for j in range(i,points):
  if distance(i,j) < treshold
    delete(j)
```

or delete the 2 points and add a point that have average coordinates

2) From point one, this question became "how to connect a 3D point to the related pixel in the left image" (it is the only interpretation). 
The answer simply is: use the projection equation. If you have K (intrinsic matrix), R (rotation matrix) and t (translation vector) from calibration of the left camera, join R and t in a 3x4 matrix

```
[R|t]
```

and then connect the M 3D point in 4-dimensional coordinates (X,Y,Z,1) as an m point (u,v,w)

```
m = K*[R|t]*M
```

divide m by its third coordinate w and you obtain

```
m = (u', v', 1)
```

u' and v' are the pixel coordinates in the left image.

Comment: Thanks a lot @marcoresk. 

I think for merging 3D point cloud I can use nearest neighbour or some form of distance measure.

However, my cameras are non static, I have the intrinsic matrix K  but how do I find R and T ? I have no predefined world coordinate system. Pardon me if I sound naive, I am still in the process of learning

Comment: @Beginner_In_Image_Processing you are welcome, I am in the process of learining too. I supposed that the sentence "I have a parallel trinocular setup where all 3 cameras" meant "reciprocal positions/orientation of the 3 camera are fixed, with respect to the left camera". I assumed also that a set of disparity is a "static" object, a single frame "frozen" in time. So you can retrieve R and te by performing some procedure of stereo calibration like [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stereo_calib.cpp). Your world coordinate system is setted as origined in left cam

Comment: @Beginner_In_Image_Processing if you have to merge points taken in different instant of time when you move your (assumed rigid in previous comment) trinocular system, then things become harder. Next time remember to specify wether your cameras ar in movement or not. If you have appreciated my answer, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, After a little bit of brainstorming, I also remembered that while generating 3D points, the left camera is considered as the origin of WCS. With your help, these are the steps that I hope to implement.

1. The camera setup is mounted on a car, so all 3 cameras move simultaneously.

2. Since the origin of 3D points for LC and LR combination is the Left camera, I can merge them simply based on distance measure without applying any rotation and translation to the 3D points.

Comment: For the CR combination however, the origin of 3D points is the centre camera. I have to rotate and translate the 3D points from centre camera to the left camera.

I can recover the relationship between L&C camera during stereo camera calibration.

Now all 3D points have the left camera as their origin. I now hope to obtain pixel locations for these 3D points using the projection matrix P, where P = K[R|t]. 

Since the origin of WCS coincides with the origin of left camera, R will be an identity matrix and translation vector will be 0.

Comment: Now, my question to you is - IS THIS CONCEPT THEORETICALLY AND MATHEMATICALLY CORRECT ?

Comment: @Beginner_In_Image_Processing Yes, I think it is, with the specification that the car is still not moving and/or you are merging 3D points from "contemporaneous frames" (I wanted to specify it not because what you wrote, only because I do not want to give you false information )

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and best of luck for your future endeavours :) Cheers (Y)